# html.actionlink not creating right links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have my routes configured like this in my global.asax

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           "poems-by-profile", // Route name
           "profile/{id}/{name}/poems", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "poems", action = "Index", id = "", name = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "profile", // Route name
           "profile/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "profile", action = "Index", id = "", name = "" } // Parameter defaults
       );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Here are my two controllers

```
public class ProfileController : BaseController
{
    public  ActionResult Index(int id, string name)
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class PoemsController : BaseController
{

    public ActionResult Index(int id, string name)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Somewhere on home page, I have html action link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "index", "Profile", new { id = 1, name = "someuser" })

@Html.ActionLink("Poems by ", "index", "poems", new { id = 1, name = "someuser" })
```

I am expecting two urls like

```
http://localhost/profile/1/someuser
http://localhost/profile/1/someuser/poems
```

But it is not creating these urls.

Am I doing something wrong.

Help will be appreciated.

//Updating my question here

Actually this one works

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "index", "Profile", new { id = 1, name = "someuser" },null)

@Html.ActionLink("Poems by ", "index", "poems", new { id = 1, name = "some user" },null)
```

Passing null as last parameter.

Dont know why, but it works.

Cheers

Parminder

Comment: what are the links you actually generate?

Comment: @Floradu88 it was generating home page link (http://localhost/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "index", new {controller="Profile" id = 1, name = "someuser" })
```

Comment: Thanks, 3nigma. It works. I have updated my question. So one more option also works.

Comment: 3nigma can't u focus on ur exams at least for some time :P